# is any api or plugin available to share image with Instagram?

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, instagram

Sorry for the question without a code.But I didn't find anywhere to look for.

I want to share image with title in instagram like facebook? How can i do that?

Is any API or plugin available to share image with Instagram?

Comment: Do you want to do this programmatically or are you looking for something like "Share on Twitter" like the SO "share" link does?

Comment: like Share on twitter..

Comment: Petrichor : Do  you have any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. Go to the bottom of this page:

https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media

> At this time, uploading via the API is not possible. We made a
>   conscious choice not to add this for the following reasons:
>
> 1)  Instagram is about your life on the go – we hope to encourage photos
>   from within the app.
>
> 2) We want to fight spam & low quality photos. Once we allow uploading
>   from other sources, it's harder to control what comes into the
>   Instagram ecosystem. All this being said, we're working on ways to
>   ensure users have a consistent and high-quality experience on our
>   platform.